# Set DatetimeField format of django rest framework configuration

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, serialization, django-rest-framework

I try to use DRF serializers to serialize a model object. I find the DatetimeField in object won't output `"2015-10-21T09:28:53.769000Z"` of the ISO-8601 format

I lookup DRF document why I can't output ISO-8601 format. According to [datetimefield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield) says:

> `format` - A string representing the output format. If not specified, this defaults to the same value as the DATETIME_FORMAT settings key, which will be 'iso-8601' unless set. Setting to a format string indicates that to_representation return values should be coerced to string output. Format strings are described below. Setting this value to None indicates that Python

It means It's default to output `iso-8601` format if I never set `DATETIME_FORMAT` argument? Not yet, it's still no change.

When I try to write setting of django project as the following:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "iso-8601",
}
```

or I write in DatetimeField argument as the following:

```
class UserSerializer(...):
    last_login = DatetimeField(format='iso-8601')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'displayname', 'is_active',
                  'date_joined', 'last_login')
```

It's still no change again.

Anyone know how to set it?

Comment: `DatetimeField in object won't output "..." of the ISO-8601 format` What does it output ?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue ! If I use the validated_data of this field, it outputs something like "2018-01-12 10:20:55" (which may be the default representation of a datetime object ?). My understanding of the doc is that the output should be "2018-01-12T10:20:55+00:00". I call isoformat() on the validated_data to have a proper format for now, but I must have missed something...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you don't konw what happen and you still don't slove that, I can define a datettime format in setting as the following:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ",
}
```

Comment: This only works if you server TIME_ZONE config is in UCT.  Z indicates that that time is UTC and you are forcing a 'Z' at the end of the format. If you want to indicate the location correctly must set %Z or %z.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to define `DATETIME_FORMAT` in settings or `format` in `last_login` field as `iso-861` is the default format.

Here is a sample example showing the serialized output of a datetime field in `iso-861` format.

```
In [1]: from rest_framework import serializers

In [2]: from datetime import datetime

In [3]: class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   ....:     last_login = serializers.DateTimeField()
   ....:     

In [4]: x = SomeSerializer(data={'last_login':datetime.now()})

In [5]: x.is_valid()
Out[5]: True

In [6]: x.data # representation of 'last_login' will be in iso-8601 formatted string
Out[6]: OrderedDict([('last_login', u'2015-10-22T09:32:02.788611Z')])
```